# Piedra papel y tijeras con JS

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estoy tratando de hacer un juego de piedra papel y tijeras con JS, pero al momento de traer información de un formulario estoy obteniendo como resultado null al elemento que quiero que tenga el valor, dejo mi código.

No veo la razón por la que no lo esté trayendo.

```
var p1 = document.getElementById("player1");

function getRandom() {
    return Math.random();
  }

var p2

if (getRandom == 0) {
    p2 = "papel"
} else if (getRandom == 1) {
    p2 = "tijeras"
} else {
    p2 = "piedra"
}

if (p1 == p2) {
    console.log(empate)
} else if(p1 == "papel" && p2 == "piedra") {
    console.log("ganaste")
    var resultado = "<p>ganaste</p>"
} else if (p1 == "tijeras" && p2 == "papel") {
    console.log("ganaste")
    var resultado = "<p>ganaste</p>"
} else if (p1 == "piedra" && p2 == "tijeras") {
    console.log("ganaste")
    var resultado = "<p>ganaste</p>"
} else {
    console.log("perdiste")
}


var traer = function(){
var p3 = document.getElementById("player1");
}

console.log(p1)


console.log(p2)
```

Comment: @BetaM ya lo arreglé, pero el console.log(p1) me sigue arrojando null

Comment: @BetaM ya lo cambié

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código tiene muchos huecos de programación, te voy a dejar un código que te puede funcionar.

**No estas obteniendo el valor de player1**

El hacer `var p1 = document.getElementById("player1");` te retorna un selector, no el valor que ingresaste, debes sacar su valor así `const p1  = document.getElementById("player1").value;`

**Acostumbrate en la medida de lo posible usar const o let**

Utiliza menos memoria en el heap que `var`

**Recuerda - es +**
Te puse un arreglo con las 3 posibilidades, el hecho que tu lo hicieras con un random, nunca te daría una tercera opción, en primera por que `Math.random()` te regresa un decimal, no un entero siempre te saldría piedra, pues nunca será ni 0 ni 1. Tendrías que pasarlo por `Math.round( Math.random() )` Pero eso es una decisión binaria, tampoco tendrías una tercera opción. Así que hice un array y de ahí sacamos un elemento random.

**En la medida de lo posible usa equidad, no igualdad**
No es lo mismo usar `==` que `===` puede ser el éxito de tu programa o el total fracaso. Siempre usa `===` a menos que las reglas de negocio indiquen lo contrario

```js
function play() {
  const posibilities = [ 'piedra', 'papel', 'tijeras' ]; 
  const p1   = document.getElementById("player1").value;
  const p2   = posibilities[ Math.floor(Math.random() * posibilities.length) ];
  
  if( !p1 ) return;
  if (p1 === p2) {
      console.log('empate');
  } else if(p1 === "papel" && p2 === "piedra") {
      console.log("ganaste")
  } else if (p1 === "tijeras" && p2 === "papel") {
      console.log("ganaste")
  } else if (p1 === "piedra" && p2 === "tijeras") {
      console.log("ganaste")
  } else {
      console.log("perdiste")
  }

}
```

```html
<input id="player1">
<button onclick="play()">Jugar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues... hay diferentes razones por las cuales tu codigo no hace lo que esperas, en primeras:

- No estas ejecutando tu funcion `getRandom`.
- Tienes una variable suelta llamada `p2` la cual probablemente siempre tendra como valor piedra, puesto que las primeras dos condiciones de asignación casi nunca se cumplirán, por no decir que nunca.
- Estas intentando comparar un elemento `HTML` (p1) con algo que nisiquiera tiene contenido y genera un error (p2).
- `p3` es igual a `p1`, por lo tanto `p3` es redundante puesto que `p1` ya tiene el valor que necesitas.
- Estas intentando comparar una funcion entera con un numero en vez de la ejecucion de la funcion.
- No estas tomando en cuenta que `Math.random` devuelve numeros flotantes (numeros decimales), por lo tanto tus condiciones asi las corrijas no se cumpliran nunca, debes primero redondear los numeros obtenidos por `Math.random`.

En este caso son demasiados errores por corregir, sin mencionar que no tiene sentido el hecho de comparar un elemento `HTML` con un string, como lo haces aqui:

```
(p1 == "papel" && p2 == "piedra"){}
```

Pues esa condicion nunca se cumplira, debido a que `p1` es un elemento `HTML` y `p2` nisiquiera tiene contenido, es como si intentaras comparar una ballena con un tanque de guerra, simplemente no tiene sentido.

Conclusión: estas confundido y debes plantear mejor el problema, no hay mucho que se pueda hacer sin cambiar casi que totalmente todo el código, pues la solución al código no se puede abarcar sin cambiar mucho del código.